# Building a Custom forms and Javascript/jQuery wont affect certain elements

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to build a custom form's system for my own CMS now this works for the most part i have a "std" text for the form and i have Textarea, Input text and these all work,

I'm using jQueryUI sortable to allow users to drag from a tooltip on the left handside to the rightPain that when and element is droped it returns it to the tool tip then copies the Template element this all works perfectly now to get the order sent to the server i have used a replace name system,

E.G

The drop down template use's,

```
<div id="dropdown" class="item">
    <div class="title">Dropdown Field</div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="error" style="display:none;">There are error in this element</div>
         <input class="type" type="hidden" name="items[%itemid%][type]" value="group" />
         Label : <br />
         <input type="text" class="label" name="items[%itemid%][label]" value="<?php echo $this->currentItem["label"]; ?>" /><br />
         Options :<br />
         <textarea name="items[%itemid%][options]" class="text_area"><?php echo $this->currentItem["options"]; ?></textarea>
         <div class="delete">
            <img src="<?php $this->getImagePath() ?>/delete.png" title="delete item" alt="a Rex X" />
            <span class="comment">Delete this Item</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

just before submiting the form i have some jQuery code that replace the name to an ordered form here is the code for that,

```
function buildOrder(){
    window.count = 0;
    $(".rightPain > div.item").each(function(){
        window.count++;
        var currentItem = $(this);
        $("input, select, textarea", $(currentItem)).each(function() {
            $(this).attr('name', $(this).attr('name').replace('%itmid%', window.count));
        });
    });
    delete window.count;
}
```

Now as i said the above code works with "std"Text, Text Field, File Field, Textarea, password and Submit/Reset buttons,

It's only the dropdown, and group select that does not work the even stranger thing is that the window.count is incremented so if i put a

> dropdown in to the form, 
>   group into the form, 
>   Std Text into the form,

The `%itemid%` is changed to `3` on the Std Text but the dropdown and group still say `%itemid%` what i find strange is that the using the `.replace(//,window.count)` should normally result in the `%itemid%` changing to  or to `undefined` but this does not happen the really strange thing is i have added a `console.log($(this))` into the buildOrder functions .each select and it is selecting the elements it just not replacing there name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(this).attr('name', $(this).attr('name').replace('%itmid%', window.count));
```

should be %itemid% instead of %itmid% I assume